# What is the time complexity of the following expression?

Tags: algorithm, time-complexity

T(n) = 16T(n/4) + n!

I know it can be solved using Master theorem, but I don't know how to handle 
f(n) = n!

Comment: Did you checked the time complexity calculating procedure described [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11032015/how-to-find-time-complexity-of-an-algorithm?answertab=active#tab-top)?

Comment: @masud_moni yes. I was not able to find anything useful.

Comment: what have you tried? have you tried unrolling it a few times to look at the pattern? anyway this is case 3 of Master Theorem

Comment: @softwarenewbie7331 Here, a = 16, b = 4, f(n) = n!. What should I take the value of c as?

Answer (score 2):

This is case three of Master Theorem.

Since `T(n) = 16T(n/4) + n!`

Here f(n) = n!.

a = 16 and b = 4, so log<sub>b</sub> a = log<sub>4</sub> 16 = 2.

Master Theorem states that the complexity T(n) = Θ(f(n)) if
c >  log<sub>b</sub> a where f(n) ∈ Ω(n<sup>c</sup>) . 
Since f(n) = n! > n<sup>c</sup> for some value of n > n<sub>0</sub> the statement  f(n) ∈ Ω (n<sup>c</sup>) is true. Thus the statement 
c >  log<sub>b</sub> a =2 is also true. Hence by the third case of Master Thoerem the complexity **T(n) = Θ(f(n)) =  Θ(n!)**.